# How can I specify the outgoing mail server in a script that uses the PHP mail() function?

Tags: php, smtp

I'm using a PHP mail script that I purchased a license for, called FormToEmail (I suspect the recent product with this name is different to my older one). It uses the PHP mail() function to send emails, but they're being sent from my host's default web server. I want the script to send emails using my outgoing mail server instead. I've tried the following to no avail - hopefully it at least helps illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$mail->Host="mail.mydomain.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username= "mymailbox@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password= "mypassword";
$mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using `mail()` but are using PHPMailer.

Comment: @JohnConde I don't believe it's PHPmailer.

Comment: Here's a line from the script help: This is a PHP script. In order for it to run, you must have PHP (version 4.1.0 or later) on your webhosting account, and have the PHP mail() function enabled and working.

Comment: The code I've pasted in the question very well may be for PHPMailer, and be why it doesn't work on my mail() script.